# SOAP Operation not found if WSA Action is null

Tags: soap, apache-axis

There is an old Axis2 V1.6.3 server which I tried to upgrade to 1.8.2.

After the upgrade, server responds for all SOAP client requests:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: 
The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is https://<servername>:8443/axis2/services/<ServiceName> and the WSA Action = null.
If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator
```

This could be easily fixed if SOAP clients would add a HTTP header

```
"SOAPAction: urn:<operationName>"
```

However, I have no control of the clients. All I can change is the server side. Old clients are out and must be still supported. Old Clients do not send HTTP Headers.

Old server obviously took **first child element** of the request and **used it as operation name**.

This is what clients are sending:

```
curl --insecure -v -X POST https://<servername>:8443/axis2/services/<ServiceName>\
  --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" \
  --data '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ccar="http://...."> \
            <soapenv:Header>\
            </soapenv:Header>\
            <soapenv:Body>\
                <ccar:<operationName1>\
                    <ccar:identifier>00123456</ccar:identifier>\
                </ccar:operationName1> \
            </soapenv:Body>\
        </soapenv:Envelope>'
```

How should I configure the Axis2 server to support such requests?

This is some Server Code:

```
@WebService(name="ServiceName")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class Service {
    @WebMethod(action="operationName1")
    public OMElement operationName1(OMElement request) {
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```